# Symbol "|" in Objective C

Tags: c

What does this line represent? Please any one explain about `|` symbol?

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with objective c. this is a c operator. pls don't open for any c operator a question.

Comment: Can you explain me `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` in Operator, or C ?

Comment: why is this getting retaged to objective-c? at least leave the c tag

Answer (score 1):

`|` is bitwise OR operator.

You can find more on it [here](http://processing.org/reference/bitwiseOR.html).

the values of both the constanst are as, it find bitwise on them.

```
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth  = 1 << 1 //2

UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight = 1 << 4 //16
```

This will be :

```
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight = 18
```